# JQuery Mobile - appending text areas to existing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am looking to append a new, (create dynamically) text area in JQuery Mobile on my web page. I have a multiple select box at the top of my page, and depending on which selections I pick I would like to add x number of text areas. How might I start this off?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Home</h1><!--Header text-->
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form method="post" data-id="two">
                <label for="select-choice-6" class="select">Search by:</label>
                <select name="select-choice-6" id="select-choice-6" class="select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                    <option>Search by:</option>
                    <option value="id">Student ID</option>
                    <option value="permit">Permit</option>
                    <option value="license">License Plate</option>
                    <option value="first">First Name</option>
                    <option value="last">Last Name</option>
                    <option value="lot">Lot Code</option>
                </select>
```

---

```
                <script>
                //.......

                    for(var j = 0; j < counts; j++)
                    {
                        $('form', "#two").append("<textarea name=\"textarea\""+(j+1)+" id=\"textarea+\""+(j+1)+" placeholder=\"");

                        var str = stuffArray.pop();
                        alert(str);
                        switch(str)
                        {
                            case "id":
                                $('form', "#two").append("Student ID");
                            break;
                            case "permit":
                                $('form', "#two").append("Parking Permit");
                            break;
                            case "license":
                                $('form', "#two").append("License Plate");
                            break;
                            case "first":
                                $('form', "#two").append("First Name");
                            break;
                            case "last":
                                $('form', "#two").append("Last Name");
                            break;
                            case "lot":
                                $('form', "#two").append("Lot");
                            break;
                            default:
                            alert("default case");
                            break;
                        }
                        $('form', "#two").append("\"></textarea><br>");
                        $("#home").trigger("create");

                    }
                //......
                </script>
```

stuffArray is a String array that holds the values of the boxes the user wants. This second bit of code here is simply to append the right tags to make a text area appear but there seems to be a hiccup in the code.

Comment: can you try `"<textarea/><br/>"` and see if it works?

Comment: @Spokey, would you like me to add this in my fifth line from the bottom in my second code section. Edit: no that does not change anything

Comment: atlually, I can't find the id `two`. did you mean the `data-id`?

Comment: @Spokey changing it to "form#[data-id='two']" does not work neither

Comment: try without the `#`. just `form[data-id='two']`

Comment: @Spokey now it simply prints out the placeholder text but no text area

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31147/discussion-between-jim-rilye-and-spokey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

Added a div to the form for holding the text areas:

```
<!-- A new div in the DOM for holding the text areas -->
<div id="text-areas"></div>
```

And here is the commented JavaScript:

```
// Bind an event handler to the change event (when the selected options change)
$("#select-choice-6").change(function() {
    // Create an empty array for pushing string values (this is more efficient than appending strings)
    var stringBuilder = [];
    // Empty the text-areas div so it doesn't accumulate text areas
    $("#text-areas").empty();
    $("#select-choice-6 option").each(function(index, item){
        // For each option in the select, check if it is selected
        if($(item).prop("selected")){
            // Push a new text area onto the stringBuilder array
            var textAreaName = "textarea" + index;
            var textAreaPlaceholder = $(item).html();
            stringBuilder.push("<textarea name='");
            stringBuilder.push(textAreaName);
            stringBuilder.push("' id='");
            stringBuilder.push(textAreaName);
            stringBuilder.push("' placeholder='");
            stringBuilder.push(textAreaPlaceholder);
            stringBuilder.push("'></textarea>");
        }
    });
    // After iterating over all options, join the array of strings into one and append it to the text-areas div
    $("#text-areas").append(stringBuilder.join(''));
});
```

And here is a link to the working JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/V3VS8/)